# Difference between // and /// in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-documentation

When I type `///`, Visual Studio shows me some parameters like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
```

What is the difference between `//` and `///` in C#?

Comment: no difference in c#. only diff is in tools.

Comment: @mohammad, You can accept the answer that helps you most by clicking the checkmark below the voting bars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a big difference.

**First**: XML comments will be shown on 
[tooltips and auto complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion).
Try writing XML comments and while writing the function notice how what you wrote in XML comments pops out while you type the function.

[image: http://s2.postimg.org/7synvskzt/Untitled.png]

**Second**: you can easily use [tools to generate complete documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381/generating-documentation-from-c-sharp-xml-comments).

See also [the official explanation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx)

Comment: another question is here: what are the a: and b:?

Comment: its a suggestion by the autocomplete to use those as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx
probably because I use RESHARPER or VISUALASSISTX

Answer (score 1):

They're both comments that won't be compiled. When you type /// in Visual Studio, it'll generate those comments for you. You can use those XML comments as documentation.

Anything typed after the first `//` are treated as a comment (not compiled code). Your IDE, which is Visual Studio, uses these special XML comments to do things like show details about a method/type/etc through Intellisense.

Comment: Not true. Triple-slashes enable XML documentation comments for classes, interfaces, methods, etc. Double-slashes are simple comments.

Comment: Oops, didn't mean that. Meant to say that both of them are comments and that the triple slashes are XML documentation. Editing my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

The // comments are normal comments while /// comments are generally called xml comments. They can be utilized to make detailed help document for you classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you use ///, it will generate comments based on the function header (as you see in your example), which can then be referenced when you use the function elsewhere.  For example, if I had the following:

```
///<summary>
///Does cool things
///</summary>
///<param name="x">A cool number</param>
//There's another for return, I don't remember the exact format:
///<return>A frigid number</return>
int function(int x)
```

If I were to write this somewhere else:

```
int a = function(b);
```

I can put my mouse over "function" and a little window will pop up, with a summary that it does cool things and explaining that it takes a cool number and returns a frigid one.  This will also work for overloads, so you can scroll through each overload header and put different summaries/variable explanations on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Single-line comment (// ):

   - It can start with ' // '
   - It is a single line comment.

**Example:**

```
main()
{
   cout<<"Hello world";   //'cout' is used for printing the output, it prints Hello world
}
```

In the above example, with the // comment, describing the use of 'cout' statement.

2. XML Documentation comment (///):

   - It is used for XML documentation.
   - It provides information about code elements such as functions, fields and variables.

**Example:**

```
///<summary>
///   Example 1
///   Using <summary> rag
///</summary>
```

For detailed info go through below link:

[C#.NET Difference between // comments, /* */ comments and /// comments](http://www.careerride.com/C-net-comment.aspx)